# Find if there is matrix that satisfying the following conditions

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, matrices

Given a matrix $A_{n\times n} = \{a_{ij}\}$ such that $a_{ij}$ is a non-negative number and given 2 vectors $(r_1,r_2,...,r_n)$ , $(c_1,c_2,...,c_n)$ such that $r_i,c_i\in \mathbb{Z}$ define an efficient algorithm that will determine if there's a matrix $B_{n\times n} = \{b_{ij}\}$ , $b_{ij} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and

for every $1\leq i \leq n \sum b_{ij} = r_i$

for every $1\leq j \leq n \sum b_{ij} = c_j$

and

$0 \leq b_{ij} \leq a_{ij}$

Thought something with dynamic programming but didn't manage to solve it.

Comment: $b_{ij} \leq a_{ij}$ is where they are used. Since your constraints are all linear, do you mean an algorithm more efficient than linear programming?

Comment: I'm looking to the most efficient algorithm, might be linear programming but still couldn't figure out how to convert it to a linear programming problem

Comment: Linear programming does not help a lot here since you are looking for integers. Unless you can prove that the polytope of this problem is integral..

Comment: For the formulation, you can consider each entry of $B$ as a variable. The three constraints can be translated directly. Note that this does not role out non-integral solutions.

Comment: However, total unimodularity of the constraint matrix can be doable. I did not say it is not the case. Write down the LP formulation and look-up the proof of unimodularity of the incidence matrix of bipartite graphs. This should be a similar proof (if it was unimodular)

Comment: Such matrices are known as *contingency tables*, and even when $a_{ij} = \infty$, counting them is #P-hard, even for only two rows!

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, but isn't the solution by D.W. correct? (Can be also seen as a bipartite b-matching formulation)

Comment: @narekBojikian Same issue as with perfect matchings (which is a special case). Counting is hard, determining if any exists is easy.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice that your statement was about counting them since the question was only about finding a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint #1:

> This can be solved with network flow.

Hint #2:

> Imagine $r_i$ units of flow entering the $i$th row, and $c_j$ units of flow leaving the $j$th column.  Does that give you any hints how to set up the graph for a network flow problem?

Comment: What kind of train of thought was it that identified network flows a plausible solution?

Comment: @Sudix, for me, I think that I tried to solve it for the special case of 0-or-1 instead of arbitrary integers; and I think I noticed that there was summing of variables and upper/lower bounds on the variables and the variables were integers, which reminded me of network flow.  In retrospect, a more direct path to it would have been the comments about linear programming and total unimodularity: network flow is a special case of linear programming where total unimodularity holds.